# iPhone Sdk Retrieving current city from coordinates

Tags: iphone

in my application i have location coordinates. i want to show city name in label instead of coordinates. how to achieve that.
Any suggestions will highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [Reverse Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding) and you will want to check out [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKReverseGeocoder) and [MKReverseGeocoderDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoderDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)